# Is there a valid Stackexchange for my home networking question, or should I just use the DD-WRT Forum?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, migrated-marker

I asked a question at serverfault, it was migrated to superuser, and promptly closed as off-topic.

Here is the question:

[Is it possible to throw DD-WRT on a F5D8235-4 v2?](https://superuser.com/questions/343784/is-it-possible-to-throw-dd-wrt-on-a-f5d8235-4-v2)

Now is there a valid stackexchange for this, or should I take my question to the DD-WRT Forums?

Comment: Since you accepted an answer: Your question wasn't actually off topic as the discussion below indicates. See Diago's answer in this very topic, as well as [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3566/should-home-networking-questions-be-considered-on-topic/3567#3567).

Comment: Okay switched selected answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am slightly confused as to why this question was closed. In my mind it is valid, except it might need to be more specific as it does border on gaining opinions, however I don't consider the topic of the question off topic.

Since it was closed by a moderator I will not override the decision, however I do see it is gaining reopen votes from the community.

**Side Note** Actually after reading it again I actually think it's a good template for a canonical, *Does DD-WRT support my Model X router* type question which can be used to close future duplicates if it is generalized a bit.

Comment: So which Stackexchange is it valid for?  None?

Comment: @leeand00 Not sure where the confusion is but it's on topic for SuperUser.

Comment: I agree, thank you for your trouble Diago!

Answer (score 2):

SU tends to dislike computers that aren't “real” computers (whatever that means). PDAs such as smartphones are definitely off-topic, but home networking equipment is usually given a pass.

If your question is related to a unix-based firmware such as *WRT, you can ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), where all Linux-based systems are on-topic regardless of the hardware you're running on. (Note: this is about scope only. I do not guarantee an answer, I think SU's WRT community is bigger than U&L's.) U&L isn't a place for questions about home networking in general: if your router isn't Linux-based or your question isn't about the router itself but about general networking matters, U&L isn't the right place for it.

Comment: Okay well, with the Belkin OS on there (which is likely Linux) than maybe that's the best place for it.  Doesn't matter to me now that I got my answer, but I'm sure given the amount of discussion this sparked in the community at large, that maybe it will hone the rules of the site a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither Server Fault nor Super User really is valid for home networking questions, and both consider it off topic. As nhinkle said:

> Yes, I did notice the migration. Sometimes users on other sites are
>   not as familiar with what's on-topic for other sites. Home networking
>   equipment is generally off-topic on both sites, except insofar as
>   interactions between computers go. If you feel that the site's scope
>   should be adapted to include home networking you can bring that up on
>   Meta Super User.

I do intend to see i[f we should be including this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3566/should-home-networking-questions-be-considered-on-topic) though in our scope for on topic questions.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that SU is not valid for home networking questions, it is 100% on topic and always has been as far as I was aware.

Comment: @Diago Hence why i made the meta post :P

Comment: I would also disagree with "SU not being the best place" for it as I have asked about a DDWRT router for a home network. Hell, if my [PXE Boot on DDWRT](http://superuser.com/questions/337877/how-can-i-set-up-a-pxe-boot-server-on-dd-wrt) is valid, this should be. I've also got [this question](http://superuser.com/q/327034/35261). Voted to re-open.

Comment: @tombull89 Actually I agree, we even have a tag for it.